# How do you get the website title to show up in the menu area / webpage title are in python / quickly created web browser?

Tags: application-development, python, quickly

hi there im creating a web browser using a mix of quickly and Python, im wanting to get a websites title to show up in the very top of the page.  im not sure of what code that i need adding to the file, ive looked all over the internet and that has been of no use.

this is the code i have got for the browser so far :

```
import gettext
from gettext import gettext as _
gettext.textdomain('dmbrowser')

from gi.repository import Gtk, WebKit # pylint: disable=E0611
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('dmbrowser')

from dmbrowser_lib import Window
from dmbrowser.AboutDmbrowserDialog import AboutDmbrowserDialog
from dmbrowser.PreferencesDmbrowserDialog import PreferencesDmbrowserDialog

# See dmbrowser_lib.Window.py for more details about how this class works
class DmbrowserWindow(Window):
    __gtype_name__ = "DmbrowserWindow"

    def finish_initializing(self, builder): # pylint: disable=E1002
        """Set up the main window"""
        super(DmbrowserWindow, self).finish_initializing(builder)

        self.AboutDialog = AboutDmbrowserDialog
        self.PreferencesDialog = PreferencesDmbrowserDialog

        # Code for other initialization actions should be added here.
        self.backbutton = self.builder.get_object("backbutton")
        self.forwardbutton = self.builder.get_object("forwardbutton")
        self.refreshbutton = self.builder.get_object("refreshbutton")
        self.stopbutton = self.builder.get_object("stopbutton")
        self.urlentry = self.builder.get_object("urlentry")
        self.scrolledwindow = self.builder.get_object("scrolledwindow")
        self.toolbar = self.builder.get_object("toolbar")

        context = self.toolbar.get_style_context()
        context.add_class(Gtk.STYLE_CLASS_PRIMARY_TOOLBAR)

        self.webview = WebKit.WebView()

        self.scrolledwindow.add(self.webview)
        self.webview.show()

    def on_backbutton_clicked(self, widget):
        self.webview.go_back()

    def on_forwardbutton_clicked(self,widget):
        self.webview.go_forward()


    def on_refreshbutton_clicked(self, widget):
        self.webview.reload()

    def on_stopbutton_clicked(self, widget):
        self.webview.stop_loading()

    def on_urlentry_activate(self, widget):
        url = widget.get_text()

        self.webview.open("http://" + url)

        print url
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but the following should work.

```
self.webview.connect('notify::title', self._title_changed_cb)

def _title_changed_cb(self, webview, title):
    self.set_title(webview.get_title())
```

You'll probably want a better title, like `"%s - %s" % (title, APPNAME)`.

**Edit**: Apprently you can't use the `title` property directly because it's a GParamString type. Just retrieve the title from the webview.

Comment: Cheers @timo so if i add that directly to the code ive been working n should it start displaying the webpage title in the menu?

Comment: @DriftedMass: yes, but in the right place ofcourse :-). The connect should go right after the webview creation and the callback handler can go anywhere in your class.

Comment: when i tried that code i got this error message when running the program via command prompt

self.webview.connect('notify::title', self._title_changed_cb)

def _title_changed_cb(self, webview, title):
    self.set_title(title)

that is the message i get, i put the connector here :

 self.toolbar = self.builder.get_object("toolbar")
        self.webview = WebKit.WebView()
        self.webview.connect('notify::title', self._title_changed_cb)

any idea of what i have done wrong?

Comment: @DriftedMass: please note that formatting gets lost in the comments which makes it hard to see what you're saying. I've made a change to my answer which fixed an error, maybe that's what you are trying to say.

Comment: Yeah im guessing all that mumbo jumbo that i had entered was saying it produced an error. Sorry for that @timo i could see any other way of adding the error code

Comment: i have now got it to work after reading a few things, i have been using Google but Google is not always best for everything, sometimes it is best to ask some one that knows what they are doing for some help.  Sorry if you have been offended by someone asking questions that they would like answers to from someone who actually knows what they are doing!

Comment: @DriftedMass: I wasn't trying to offend you in any way! I'm glad if I can help you, but you must understand that programming is more than asking advice from others. You won't learn things in a couple of days, you'll have to read and read and read even more! Try to find and understand things yourself, it'll help you out a lot more in the long run. Most questions you ask aren't too hard figuring out yourself, that's why I was trying to give you some heads up, it wasn't meant to be negative in any way!

Comment: i understand you were not trying to offend me, i had just been asking because i had been working on it for a while and i could not figure out a way of implementing it.  I figured out when you added the code that i was using code that is now outdated so that was the reason that it would not work properly

Answer (score 0):

```
   self.webview.connect('load_committed', self.change_url)
def change_url(self, widget, data=None):
   self.urlentry.set_text( widget.get_main_frame().get_uri() )
```

it will work check out